# Storing values in appSettings

Tags: c#, wpf, config

I am attempting to store a userID in my config file which I then want to access throughout my program for numerous reasons. I have the `appSettings` section in the config file like so;

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="userID" value="1" />
</appSettings>
```

I then set the value in one method;

```
private void hrButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataAccessor da = new DataAccessor();
    DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)dataGrid.SelectedItem;

    // Open App.Config of executable
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    // Add an Application Setting.
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("userID", dataRow.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString());

    // Save the changes in App.config file.
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

    da.SetUserDetails();
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(@"View/HRSystem/HRSystem.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Before attempting to access and use it in another;

```
public List<string> SetUserDetails()
{
    string userID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("userID");
    MessageBox.Show("userID: "+userID);

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbfString"].ConnectionString;
    using (OleDbConnection dbfCon = new OleDbConnection(constr))
    {
        try
        {
            dbfCon.Open();
            OleDbDataReader myReader;
            OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT em_pplid FROM employs WHERE em_pplid = "+ userID + "", dbfCon);
            myReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<string> listUser = new List<string>();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                listUser.Add(myReader[0].ToString());
                return listUser;
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

However when I show the `userID` in the message box it is still set to 1. I haven't used the `appSettings` section before, is there a reason why it is always 1? I'm running Visual Studio 2015, C# WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("userID");` on the line just above `config.AppSettings.Settings.Add();`

But the correct way to save such information is to use a [Settings File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

*Set:*

```
Properties.Settings.Default.userID = dataRow.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

*Retreive:*

```
var userId = Properties.Settings.Default.userID;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although even after doing this userID is still being set to 1

Comment: UPDATE: using the Settings File method worked instead, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove('userID');

config.AppSettings.Settings.Add('userID', dataRow.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
```

But you should not store  the user id in the configuration file. You should save it in  session or Cookie